# Gradle - can I include task's output in project dependencies

Tags: gradle

I have a task that generates java sources and a set of jars from these sources (say, project `a`). I would like to export these jars to dependent projects (say, project `b`). So here's roughly what I have right now:

```groovy
//a.gradle

configurations{
  generatedJars
}

task generateJars(type: JavaExec) { 
  //generate jars ... 

  outputs.files += //append generated jars here
} 

dependencies{
  generatedJars generateJars.outputs.files
}


//b.gradle

dependencies{
  project(path: ':a', configuration: 'generatedJars')
}
```

It works OK, except that adding `generateJars.outputs.files` as a dependency does not tell gradle that it has to run `generateJars` task when there are no jars generated yet. I have tried adding the task itself as a dependency hoping that it would work in the same way as it does when you add a jar/zip task to an artifact configuration (e.g. `artifacts{ myJarTask }`), but it throws an error telling me that I cannot do that. Of course I can inject the `generateJars` task somewhere in the build process before `:b` starts evaluating, but that's clumsy and brittle, so I would like to avoid it.

I feel like I should be adding the generated jars to `artifacts{ ... }` of the project, but I am not sure how to make them then visible to dependent projects. Is there a better way of achieving this?

Dependent projects (project `b`) will need to do setup IntelliJ IDEA module classpath to point to project `a`'s generated jars. Something rather like this (pseudo-code):

```groovy
//b.gradle

idea{
  module{
    scopes.COMPILE.plus += project(path: ':a', configuration: 'generatedJars').files
  }
}
```

So far I have tried simply adding a project dependecy on `:a`'s `generatedJars` in `:b`, but Idea plugin simply adds module `:a` as a module-dependency and assumes that it exports its generated jars (which is probably a correct assumption), therefore not adding the generated jars to `:b`'s classpath.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, do you need a separate configuration? That is, do you have clients of `a` that should *not* see the generated Jars? If not, you can add the generated Jars to the `archives` configuration, which will simplify things.

Second, the correct way to add the generated Jars to the configuration is (instead of the `dependencies` block):

```
artifacts {
    generatedJars generateJars
}
```

This should make sure that the `generateJars` task gets run automatically when needed.

Third, I'd omit the `+=` after `outputs.files`, although it might not make a difference. You should also add the necessary inputs.

Fourth, why do you need a `JavaExec` task to generate the Jars? Can you instead add the generated sources to some source set and let Gradle build them?

Fifth, IDEA doesn't have a concept corresponding to Gradle's project configuration dependencies. Either an IDEA module fully depends on another module, or not at all. You have two options: either use a module dependency and make the generated sources a source folder of the depended-on module (preferably both in the Gradle and the IDEA build), or pass the generated Jars as external dependencies to IDEA. In either case, you should probably add a task dependency from `ideaModule` to the appropriate generation task. If this still doesn't lead to a satisfactory IDEA setup, you could think about moving the generation of the Jars into a separate subproject.

Comment: Thanks. Adding the task to `artifacts` woks nicely within the module, but I don't see how can I reference those jars from project `b` (without publishing them). Yes, it is possible to generate just sources and export them as module source. This should work, but it creates extra work for IDEA, so I was hoping it could be circumvented somehow. To make hooking `ideaModule -> generateJars`  work well, I also need to add `b:ideaModule -> a:ideaModule`, and I have about 3 modules that all need to do this.  I was hoping I could set it up for automatic resolution somehow.

Comment: ad 1. `project(path: 'a', configuration: 'generatedJars')`

Comment: ad 2. Does the "extra work" matter? (You could use the same argument for the non-generated code.) In any case, you should probably compile the files with Gradle rather than a JavaExec task.

Comment: ad 3. Why would you need to add `b:ideaModule -> a:ideaModule`? Anyway, depending on when sources need to be regenerated, you might have to invoke `generateJars` manually anyway, and `ideaModule -> generateJars` might not be crucial. You could set it up as an external tool.

Comment: 1) I meant reference from `idea.module` block. `project()` appears to only work in `dependencies` clause. 2) Yes, it adds time to Idea build (more time than pre-built jars) and clutters Idea with inspection warnings that we can't do much about. 3) Because `b.iml` will be generated without the jars unless they exist on disk. I guess the real dependency here is `b:ideaModule -> a:generateJars`. Sources need to be (re)generated whenever some relevant source in `a` is modified. Functionally it should behave as any other source under project `a` ... maybe then it well should be one :S

Comment: OK, thanks a lot. It's clear enough now. I'll try exporting the sources under Idea. Also adding generated jars as `a`'s dependencies, then marking them for export in `a.iml` seems to do the trick too.

Answer (score 1):

For my use case, I had a C++ project which generated some native libraries which my java project needed to load in order to run.

#### In the project ':native' build.gradle:

```
task compile(type: Exec, group: 'build') {
    dependsOn ...

    outputs.files(fileTree('/some/build/directory') {
        include 'mylib/libmy.so'
    })

    ...
}
```

#### In project java application build.gradle:

```
configurations {
    nativeDep
}

// Add dependency on the task that produces the library
dependencies {
    nativeDep files(project(':native').tasks.findByPath('compile'))
}

// Unfortunately, we also have to do this because gradle will only
// run the ':native:compile' task if we needed the tasks inputs for another
// task
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    dependsOn ':native:compile'
}

run {
    doFirst {
        // Use the configuration to add our library to java.library.path
        def libDirs = files(configurations.nativeDep.files.collect {it.parentFile})
        systemProperty "java.library.path", libDirs.asPath
    }
}
```