# Shadow project gradle file doesn't compile

Tags: gradle

while working with shadow plugin I tried to execute my Gradle code:

```
import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.transformers.AppendingTransformer

shadow {
    transformer(AppendingTransformer) {
        resource = 'META-INF/spring.handlers'
    }
    transformer(AppendingTransformer) {
        resource = 'META-INF/spring.schemas'
    }
}
```

As a result i received the folloqing error:

```
Could not find method transformer() for arguments [class com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.transformers.AppendingTransformer, build_bdpgdpxcevq273h2385je07ue$_run_closure2_closure5@1452aad2] on project ':ProjectX'.
```

Am i missing something? where does the 'transformer' function should be defined?

Comment: What version of the shadow plugin are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question lack some information, but from the error you pasted it looks like the shadow extension does not really contain a transformer method (thus trying to find it on the owner object - project). To me it means that you are probably using one of the latest (latest being the 1.2.2 version) versions of the shadow plugin whilst trying to configure it in some old not-supported way.

In the newer versions you should configure the plugin via the

```
shadowJar {
    transform(AppendingTransformer) {
          resource = 'NOTICE'
    }
}
```

Configuration closure and not the old notiation

```
shadow {}
```

See [here](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) the new README file, and [here](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow/blob/master/README_old.md) the old README file.

Comment: Thank you very much Boaan, it compiles now but it doesn't really do anything..., Do you have any idea why??

Comment: @Adi, how are you executing the build? I suggest you'll read the new README. You're probably executing gradle build and the README says to execute gradle shadowJar

Comment: Yes Boaz you are right, i was calling the wrong compiler. do you know how can i call the shadowjar from a different project as a dependency? somthing like:  compile project(':XYZ')

Comment: @Adi, are you talking about a multi-project configuration? or a completely separate project? see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12691107/gradle-can-i-include-tasks-output-in-project-dependencies